# How can I download a Zip file using jszip in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, jszip

I created a function to download a zip file for multiple file for sharepoint.

```
 function create_zip() {
    var zip = new JSZip();

    $.each(filePathArray, function (i, path) {

        var filename = path; //"file" + i +".txt";
        var filee = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        var fileURL = appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + filename + "')/$value?@target='" + hostweburl + "'";//$('#file').attr('href');
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: fileURL,
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "text/plain",

            mimeType: 'text/plain; charset=x-user-defined' // <-[1]
        });

        request.done(function (data) {
            //var filee = "MoveFiles" + count + ".txt";
            zip.file(filee, data, { binary: true }); // <- [2]
            //count++;
            vfilecount++;
            console.log(vfilecount);
            console.log(vfilecount);

            if (count == vfilecount) {
                zip.generateAsync({ type: "base64" }).then(function (data) {

                    location.href = "data:application/zip;base64," + data;

                });

            }

        });
    });
   }
```

Now This code works proper in Chrome and mozilla but not in IE .
Please suggest any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/issues/376 (reposting it here to help others):

- `mimeType: 'text/plain; charset=x-user-defined'` doesn't work in IE 10. `$.ajax` is meant to download text content, not binary content. Same with XmlHttpRequest without setting responseType. Browsers will try to decode the received content from UTF8 and corrupt it (because it's a binary content, not a text). Use a jQuery plugin (like [jquery.binarytransport.js](https://github.com/henrya/js-jquery/tree/master/BinaryTransport)) or use a xhr directly (with `xhr.responseType = "blob"`).
- `location.href = "data:application/zip;base64," + ...` doesn't work in IE. Generate a blob instead and use [`saveAs`](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to trigger the download